# Flutter: Firebase messaging with patform channels - Duplicated FlutterActivity

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement an app using Flutter. The app should be able to send messages from the smartphones to a server using FCM or receive messages from the server via FCM.
I implemented the FCM functionality using the firebase_messaging plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging). Everything is working fine for downstream messages (server -> device). Now I tried to add upstream messages (device -> server). As far as I know from the docs, the plugin does not support upstream messages yet. So I began to write native code to send the messages to the server and call this code via platform channel functionality (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab).

Initial MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.os.Bundle

import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

Added the method channel example from Flutter docs. Using the imports specified in the Flutter docs:

```
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getBatteryLevel") {
                val batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel()

                if (batteryLevel != -1) {
                    result.success(batteryLevel)
                } else {
                    result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getBatteryLevel(): Int {
        val batteryLevel: Int
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val batteryManager = getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
            batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
        } else {
            val intent = ContextWrapper(applicationContext).registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
            batteryLevel = intent!!.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100 / intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
        }
        return batteryLevel
    }
```

But unfortunately there occurs a problem. The firebase_messaging plugin requires the mainactivity.kt to extend `io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity`. Platform channels require the mainactivity.kt to extend `io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity`.

Is there any way to use both - firebase_messaging plugin and method channels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compared my code to the example project from the firebase_messaging plugin: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/example/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebasemessagingexample/MainActivity.java

Then I realized that the example uses the `io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity` too. After changing the import statements to the `io.flutter.embedding...` package I removed the `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)` as `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` is an import from `io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant` and does not seem to match the embedding package. Then I checked the fields and functions in `io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine` again and added following line: `flutterEngine?.plugins?.add(FirebaseMessagingPlugin())`

After this I recompiled the app and at the start it prints out the FCM device ID and the battery status successfully.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.BatteryManager
import android.os.Build.VERSION
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin

class MainActivity : io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity() {

    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        flutterEngine?.plugins?.add(FirebaseMessagingPlugin())
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            call, result ->
            if (call.method == "getBatteryLevel") {
                val batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel()

                if (batteryLevel != -1) {
                    result.success(batteryLevel)
                } else {
                    result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null)
                }
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getBatteryLevel(): Int {
        val batteryLevel: Int
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            val batteryManager = getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
            batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
        } else {
            val intent = ContextWrapper(applicationContext).registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
            batteryLevel = intent!!.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100 / intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
        }
        return batteryLevel
    }
}
```